# How to make an Alchemy CMS element produce an HTML list

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-lists, alchemy-cms

I'm trying to create an Alchemy CMS element which will produce an HTML list as its result. The element in question is a navigation bar that I want to be structured as a list in HTML because that is what the CSS which I have wants to work with. E.g., I'd like to have an element specified like so in `config/alchemy/elements.yml`:

```
- name: navbar
  unique: false
  nestable_elements: [navitem]
  contents:
  - name: logo # There's also a logo in this navbar
    type: EssencePicture

- name: navitem
  contents:
    - name: navitem_content
      type: EssenceText
      settings:
        linkable: true
```

And then have this `navbar` element become an `<li>` in the actual HTML which is generated. Unfortunately, this sort of thing doesn't yet work for me because the `navbar` that is generated (which encapsulates the logo and the navigation items) is actually a `<div>`. I'm not really sure how to change a given Alchemy element to be of a type other than a `<div>` (obviously, in this case, I want it to be an `<li>`).

The only thing I've seen thus far that *might* work for doing what I want is to create an Essence with the type of `EssenceHtml`. However, I don't think that this will be sufficient since I'm trying to nest other elements / Essences inside of this one (which I don't think works for Essences) and this just seems to emit static, raw HTML.

So, I guess I'm asking what the best way is to create an Alchemy element with the tag type that I want (in this case, an `<li>`), which will also contain other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/Alchemy/ElementsBlockHelper#element_view_for-instance_method) `element_view_for` helper has a `tag` option.

Just pass `tag: 'li'` and you're all good.